# Can I use modified playtest characters in my 5e game?

Tags: dnd-5e, player-characters, dnd-next-playtest

I understand that some of the information will change, and that there are some important differences between the last playtest package and the basic rules.

For player characters I see the major changes being proficiency modifier is higher at level 1, more skills from background and less from class, and more money being dumped in to the gear from backgrounds (making starting characters that use the packages far better off in their initial gear than those who don't).

My question is, "**If I take the above things in to account, can I use the classes, builds, and races listed in the last playtest reasonably until the PHB comes out next month?**"

They seem mostly compatible with small alterations.

Comment: Since this is about both the D&D Next playtest and the published version of D&D 5e, I've added the [dnd-next-playtest] tag in addition to the existing [dnd-5e] tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mostly yes.  There are a few things you should take into account though besides what you wrote about in your question.

**Bonus actions:**  Bonus actions did not exist in the playtest but are an important "balancer" in the D&D 5e rules.  You are going to have to look at abilities that grant extra actions and turn those into bonus actions.

**Saving throws profs:** Each class now receives a proficiency bonus in two saving throws. One of the strong ones (Dex/Wis/Con) and one in the weaker ones (Str/Int/Cha).  Make sure you adjust class saving throw proficiencies as needed.

**Profciency scaling chart:** Remember to adjust the proficiency bonus at all levels, not just levels 1 and 2.

**Same name abilities:**  If you are playing a ranger or a paladin, make sure to use the Fighting styles listed under the 5e Fighter class, rather than use the abilities of the same name under the playtest classes.

**Spells:**  Spells also got quite a shake up, so try to use the 5e spells when available.

As a side note, be aware that the actual 5e classes and subclasses are likely to change quite a bit from those in the playtest, so your players might want to rebuild characters when the actually Phb comes out. It might be worth your time to delay till then, unless players are certain that they will be fine adjusting to the new rules when they have access to them.